# xpages forward o reply email

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I  need a solution, that when you press a button from a inbox xpages mail message, the new xpages is composed with the body and image and attachment of original inbox message (ckeditor control)

I nave found a Solution for passing HTML to ckeditor but not for attachment and inline image.
Have you any suggest?

P.S. the solution will need work in on-fly mode (without savind document before..so that when you foward an email with a classic webmail)

Comment: Do you copy $FILE items?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121385/copying-rich-text-and-images-from-one-document-to-mime-in-another-document

Answer (score 0):

See my answer below on how to copy contents and images to a CKEditor on the fly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328276/785061