# how insert images on fly with CKEDITOR and XSP runtime

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have used [**@Per Henrik Lausten** solution](http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/12/xpages-dynamically-updating-rich-text-content-in-a-ckeditor.html) for generate on fly content of my CKEDITOR from a backend document (I have insert into BeforePageLoad the code)

All work correctly, except that the images in notes client and in another Xpages session do not show the image because the URL of images embedded is only for the current XPages user session and I don't understand how the current Xpages know that this is temporany images and original file upload images control of CKEDITOR not.

I see that in October '13 the solution was to replace BASE64 code into IMG tag [include base 64 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121385/copying-rich-text-and-images-from-one-document-to-mime-in-another-document) but this don't work in Notes Client, but work only for XPages session(the IMG box is red into a client Notes and can't use my code to send an email with this tag)

I have the last release of Domino 9.0.1 with last ExtLib on my server...and I have debugged the **original control that upload the images** into CKEDITOR for find the difference of @Per Herink Lausten solution and the original file images upload.

But don't understand the IMG SRC tag into CKEDITOR is correctly compiled (is the same of original file upload)...but I don't understand how the XSP runtime know that the original IMG SRC file upload is different from the on-fly solution.

Have someone ay idea?

tnx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the source of this project: http://tonymcguckin.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/xpages-rich-text-editor-evolution/  You'll find all you need in there I believe... also take a look at the emailBean... http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter for more related code around manipulating / dynamically inserting images etc into the CKEd