# How do you extract data associated with an image that is an attachment to a Notes RichTextItem?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I've seen things that skirt around this question, but nothing that answers it directly.

I have a RichTextItem in a document that contains an attached image. If I look at the document properties for the field, it says:

```
Data Type: MIME Part
Data Length: 7615 bytes
...
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

then a bit of binary data.  How can I extract that data in server-side javascript so that I can use it in the value of an image control?  In other words, I want the data corresponding to that image to appear in the following so that it renders in the web browser:

```
<xp:image><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"data:image/jpeg;base64,<DATA HERE>
```

Can this be done?  I've tried all sorts of things but to no avail.

Thanks,
Reid

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Per.  I was in a hurry and didn't check my work!

Answer (score 2):

There a several approaches you can play with.

- The "cheat" way: use `....nsf/0/unid/RTItemName?OpenField` in a dojo panel as its source. (see [here](http://www.iminstant.com/iminstant/iminstant.nsf/d6plinks/ctyr-7h6s6r). It would open the whole RichText.
- Eventually you need `OpenElement` instead - can [directly address an attachment](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/)
- Last not least, since your field isn't actually RichText, but MIME, you can use the Notes MIME classes to get to the content and render it base64. The mime classes allow to get [the data as stream](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETCONTENTASBYTES_METHOD_MIMEENTITY_JAVA.html) as well as provide methods to then encode it, so you don't need an extra encoder class

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently doing your first approach in some cases. Unfortunately, I'm not able to scale my images using CSS when I do that (separate question, perhaps), so I'm trying to use an image. I will look into #2. #3 sounds like what I've been trying to do, and in theory it seems like it should work, but I haven't been able to put the right pieces together to get it to work.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you get a base64 encoding of images: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19328276/785061

Comment: Thanks, Per. That does indeed look helpful!

Comment: Well, that approach didn't get me far....  It seems the getEmbeddedImageStream call returns null in my situation.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot get stwissel's second approach (with OpenElement) to work, either.  Concrete examples (URLs and/or code) gladly accepted!