# XPages: Copy MIME multiparts from mail to another Richtext document

Tags: java, email, xpages

Trying to create an new XPages document from  email by saving the mail body into a richtext Item, my document get created properly the attachmentBody is also creted but all embeded images in the document is been replace with a imagePlace holder, below is the method that create the attachement and images

```
private static void parseMimeEntity(RichTextItem attachmentBody, MIMEEntity entity,Session session,File tmpFolder,String fileSeparator,long attachmentNumber) {
    MIMEEntity child;
        try{        
            if(!entity.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("text")){
                String filename = null; 
                MIMEHeader header = null;
                header = entity.getNthHeader("Content-Disposition");    
                if (header != null) {
                    filename = header.getParamVal("filename");
                    filename = filename.replace("\"", "");
                    if ("".equals(filename)) filename = null;
                }
                if (filename == null) {
                    // when filename is null
                    filename = "Attachment" + attachmentNumber++ + ".txt";
                }
                String contentDisposition = entity.getNthHeader("Content-Disposition").getHeaderVal();

                if(contentDisposition.equalsIgnoreCase("inline")){                      
                    String contentType = entity.getNthHeader("Content-Type").getHeaderVal();                        
                    Stream stream = session.createStream();
                    if (stream.open(file.getAbsolutePath(), "binary")) {
                        entity.setContentFromBytes(stream, contentType, MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);                        
                        stream.close();
                    }
                }else{

                Stream stream = session.createStream();
                if (stream.open(file.getAbsolutePath(), "binary")) {
                    entity.getContentAsBytes(stream);                           
                    stream.close();
                }                   
                attachmentBody.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", file.getAbsolutePath(), filename);      
                }   
                file.delete();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){                
            System.out.println("NO FILE");
        }
        child = entity.getFirstChildEntity();
        if (child != null) {
            parseMimeEntity(attachmentBody, child,session,tmpFolder,fileSeparator,attachmentNumber);
        }
        child = entity.getNextSibling();
        if (child != null) {
            parseMimeEntity(attachmentBody, child,session,tmpFolder,fileSeparator,attachmentNumber);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Did you make sure that MIME conversion is disabled, for example by setting `session.setConvertMime(false);` before creating the new document?

Comment: yes i did setConvertMime to false

Comment: in the document souce i could see the embeded image as base64 encoded but not displaying in the richtext field

Comment: Are you outputting the document content to a richtext control on the XPage? If so, you could inspect the displayed html code and check if maybe the content ids of the embedded images were not resolved properly, or if there is a problem with the base64 data uri definition...

Comment: yes i am outputtin the mail content to a richtext, and the html code contain content-ID, how can i resolve the base64 properly?

Comment: You can do the following: (1) Recursively iterate through all parts of the MIME body and check for those with Content-Type "image/*" that have a "Content-ID" header. (2) Search for the corresponding content ids (for example "cid:abc123") in the html body and replace them with the data uri generated from the part's base64 content (for example "data:image/png;base64,...").

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new mime entry, you get new boundary strings which serve as keys to the embedded images. Check the `src` attribute of the incoming image for the exact format.

You need to adjust those attributes to make the images show up properly. Cleaning up HTML is no fun, take some pointers from this article:

https://wissel.net/blog/2017/04/from-blogsphere-to-a-static-site-part-2-cleaning-up-the-html.html

Eventually (need to check, don't know that off my head) you can specify the boundaries and save you the HTML cleanup

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to Base64 encode the embedded images instead of adding the embedded images as attachments. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328276/785061.

Comment: the image is already stored on the document as Base64  but when i use maildocument.getEmbeddedImagesList("Body") it return empty list