# setting MIME Multipart as a default value of inputRichText on page load ssjs

Tags: xpages, mime, multipart, xpages-ssjs

I've a document in database which have multipart MIME content which includes text and image. And i'm trying to get that value and set as default value of another inputRichText, so that when i'll open the Xpage the value from database document should be appear as default value of that inputRichText which is included in the opened Xpage.
I've already binded that inputRichText with "Body" and i want to set a default value of that like a mail signatures.

[image]

Comment: Can this http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/12/xpages-dynamically-updating-rich-text-content-in-a-ckeditor.html and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328276/785061 help you?

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten thanks it worked partially, as at the time of sending image it wont appear to others. Because the src of img is browser link, and i got the solution so working on.